# How can I control the volume of a process by their name

Tags: c++, windows

I'm having a hard time googling this question mainly because I don't fully understand the terminology of this aspect.

Basically I want to create a C++ binding for Node.js so I can call a function to adjust the volume of a certain application, e.g. chrome.exe

In my Electron program I want them to be able to control the volume of a program if they type in the name of the executable.

But I'm having a hard time googling things like "C++ Adjust volume of a specific process / application / program", or the examples look extremely convoluted unless that really is how much effort goes into just adjusting the volume of a program. Any help would be great thanks unfortunately I do not have any code to assist with as I can't even seem to find what I'm looking for on google.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370784(v=vs.85).aspx  I also suggest looking at this answer, even though it's not C++